# Aggregate counting/sum in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to figure out how to sum up many different counts in an elasticsearch index. A document in the index looks like this:

```
{
  '_source': {
    'my_field': 'Robert and Alex went with Robert to play in London and then Robert went to London',
    'ner': {
      'persons': {
        'Alex': 1,
        'Robert': 3
      },
      'organizations': {},
      'dates': {},
      'locations': {
        'London': 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I sum up all the different words in `location`, `dates` and `persons` in the index? For example if another document had 2 occurrences of `Alex`, I'd get `Alex: 3, Robert: 3, ..`

Comment: You need count of occurrence or sum ? Both are different  and both  have different ways

Comment: @ashishtiwari Trying to get the sum

Comment: i guess sum aggregation will work for you https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html

Comment: @ashishtiwari how will this work if I can't explicitly write down the name of the field (Alex, Robert, London, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

## This will give you sum of specific field

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/yourindex/_search?size=0" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "aggs" : {
        "person_Alex" : { "sum" : { "field" : "person.Alex" } },
        "person_Robert" : { "sum" : { "field" : "person.Robert" } },
        "person_Alex" : { "sum" : { "field" : "person.Alex" } }
    }
}
'
```

## This will give you count

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/yourindex/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "aggs" : {
        "count_Alex" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "person.Alex" }
        },
        "count_Robert" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "person.Alex" }
       }
    }
}'
```

You need to specify fields.

Comment: I dont think you understand my question. I won't know the names of the field because they're automatically extracted and each document will have different fields. I want to sum the fields they have in common.